# D-Limit and Crumbling Quote Indicator

Tags: machine-learning, exchange, order-execution

I've been following the development of the [D-Limit order at IEX](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-exchange-iex-idUSKBN1YL1NG) for some time. In the last couple of days I see the [SEC has been sued by Citadel Securities for approving this order type](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-citadel-securities-sec-iex-group-laws/citadel-securities-sues-sec-over-approval-of-new-stock-order-type-idUSKBN27201E).

Can anyone explain to me how the Crumbling Quote Indicator they use works - particularly the [machine learning/AI](https://www.sec.gov/comments/sr-iex-2019-15/sriex201915-7435591-220662.pdf) component, and how they will be able to give their customers enough information about why their orders have/have not been executed during these periods?

As for the legal case, the claim is that this will harm market participants and damage liquidity - is this a reasonable claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is described in the [IEX Rule Book](https://iextrading.com/docs/Investors%20Exchange%20Rule%20Book.pdf), section 11.160 (g). See Quote Instability Factor (QFI) and the accompanying thresholds:

$$ QIF = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

where $$x = C_0 + C_1N + C_2F + C_3NC + C_4FC + C_5EPos+C_6ENeg+C_7 EPosPrev+C_8ENegPrev + C_9Delta$$

The coefficients $C_n$ are hard-coded and are updated once in a while with a corresponding SEC filing. The variables refer to the current and historical (1ms prior) order book state on other exchanges. For example:

> (9) $Delta$ = the number of these three (3) venues that moved away from
> the near side of the market on the same side of the market and were at
> the same price at any point since one (1) millisecond ago or the most
> recent PBBO change on the near side, whichever happened more recently:
> XNGS, EDGX, BATS.

In a nutshell, $QIF$ is high when other venues are departing the NBBO.

More details are available in the [Evolution of the Crumbling Quote Signal](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2956535) on SSRN.

Comment: Thanks for this!